# How to turn CSS off with links?

Tags: html, css

How to turn off CSS link in HTML?

I have this in my styles.css page

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 80px;
}
```

This makes:

```html
<li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
```

Appear horizontal.

However when I want to use an ordered list in HTML, the numbers will not appear.
I think because the CSS applies to all `<li>` tags.

Comment: Remove the `display: inline;` rule?

Comment: Rather declare a class for lists that need that particular `inline` styling and keep it scoped and separated from other concerns, for example `.inline-list li {display: inline;}`, you would apply the `inline-list` class to the parent element, whether it's `ul` or `ol`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `ul li` to only inline items in an unordered list.

```
ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 80px;
}
```

Or better, use a class to designate lists that should display inline:

```
.inline-list li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 80px;
}

<ul class="inline-list">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordered list has the `ol` tag, the `ul` tag is an unordered list

In your css, change the `ul` to `ol` and you will be able to css an ordered list

If you want the number to appear then you have to add `ol` tag.

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="home.html">About</a></li>
</ol>
```

Then, if you want them to be inline, you can do

```
li {
    padding: 80px;
}

ol {
    display: flex;
}
```

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/sngzv67o/

Comment: `li` is just an item, could be in an `ol` ordered list or `ul` unordered list

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
a:link {

text-decoration: none;

}
```

[w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link_decoration)

Answer (score 0):

At least thre exists 2 possibilities;
the first (but i guess no the one you seeked) is to specifiy the path for style, if you can something like will satisfy your need

```css
ul > li {
     display: inline;
     padding: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

this way, the inlining will only apply to unordered list items.
Another solution is to use vanilla js to explictly remove the style

```css
ul > li {
     display: inline;
     padding: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ol>
<input type='button' onclick='document.getElementsByTagName("style")[0].remove()' value='Remove style tag'>
```